# Registered event handlers in Excel stops firing on published, sideloaded Add-in

Tags: office-js

I have created an Excel Web-Add-in with Office.js and made it available to the employees of our company via sideloading for internal use.

The onSettingsChanged event is attached to the first worksheet of the excel app. In debug mode, the event is always steady fired. In the released version, there was always a slight delay. However, this has not further disturbed the usage of the Add-in. 
But recently, events are only fired the first 1-3 times and then nothing happens anymore.

If a cell has been selected, then you have to hovering with the mouse courser over the add-in to execute the event. So the event is still bound and present, but is no longer executed immediately.

I have already tested this with all other events and have the same problem with all of them. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/excel/excel-add-ins-events.md

Register function:

```
async function registerSelectionChangedHandler() {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getFirst();
            sheet.onSelectionChanged.add(onSelectionChange);

            sheet.onChanged.add(onChanged);
            sheet.onActivated.add(onActivated);
            sheet.onDeactivated.add(onDeactivated)

            await context.sync();
        });
    }
```

Execute functions:

```
    async function onChanged(event) {
        errorHandler(new Error("onChanged " + event.address));
    }

    async function onActivated(event) {
        errorHandler(new Error("onActivated"));
    }

    async function onDeactivated(event) {
        errorHandler(new Error("onDeactivated"));
    }

    async function onSelectionChange(event) {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {

            let sourceRange = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

            sourceRange.values = [["Hello World"]];
            sourceRange.format.fill.color = "3498DB";
            sourceRange.format.font.bold = true;

            await context.sync();
        });
    }
```

I would expect the events always be fired as long as the worksheet exists.

Is this a problem with the sideloading? Do I have to make settings or configurations on the Add-in or in Office?

My steps to create local test:

1. Created a new Excel Web Add-in Project with VS 2017
2. Updated all nuget packages
3. Convert Office Add-in project to TypeScript [Convert an Office Add-in project in Visual Studio to TypeScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript)
4. Added event functionality and Promise typo to Home.ts
5. Created a new website on local IIS
6. Created a new folder for the manifest and share public
7. Changed manifest "~remoteAppUrl" to the local website url
8. Published the Office Add-in project to the local website
9. Added the shared folder to the Trusted Add-in Catalogs in Excel
10. Added the Add-in to Excel

You can find the created project on [github](https://github.com/SeToBr/OfficeEventsTestAddin). The included [video](https://github.com/SeToBr/OfficeEventsTestAddin/blob/master/ScreenCapture_15.05.2019%2011.31.31.wmv) shows the behavior with the published Add-in.

Comment: We tried your scenario locally but seems can't repro it. Could you please provide your build number and also a video of your repro steps? Thanks.

Comment: @MSFT-Jipyua Sorry for my late response.

I created a sample project and uploaded a video with the behaviour in debug mode and in the released version.

https://github.com/SeToBr/OfficeEventsTestAddin.git

Office Version 1904 Build 11601.20178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue.
Could you try the workaround in [this link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/521#issuecomment-502944107)?

Paste the *updated* workaround here as well.

> Add `MutationObserver=null` to the beginning of the index.html which links office.js

Comment: It works when I set the interval to 1000. With an interval of 30000, the behavior is still present when I quickly select new cells.
For our addin it is sufficient if I start the interval only when the user has to select the cells. This allows me to clear the interval after editing.

Thanks!